# S3 Event -> Lambda vs S3->SNS->Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I'm trying to understand the behavior of S3 Event Notification trigger. I have s3 events to trigger lambda. Lambda captures the event and file metadata to dynamodb. There would be around 50k event triggers in short burst across the day. If I had to add SNS in the workflow and have SNS trigger lambda, what are the advantages with sns vs s3 directly invoking lambda?

Answer (score 8):

There is no gained advantage. Both S3 and SNS events are asynchronous event sources and behave the same way. See: [Lambda supported event sources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html#supported-event-source-sns) And: [Lambda Retry on Errors (Asynchronous invocation part)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html), which highlights nicely the lambda behavior with specific types of event sources.

Simply doing S3 -> Lambda is sufficient.

Answer (score 8):

The advantage is flexibility for the future. If you use SNS in the middle, you can easily send (fan-out) the notifications to multiple destinations with more SNS topic subscriptions -- another Lambda function, an SQS Queue, an HTTPS endpoint, or even email, which can be *very* useful for non-intrusive observation, testing, troubleshooting, and developing new capabilities that need the same notification.

Comment: While it might be an advantage if fan-out is required for the specific use-case, it is not an advantage to implement it before you need it. Adding SNS between S3 and Lambda is very simple and should be done only when you need to, otherwise you have unnecessary costs from an SNS topic that is giving you no benefits.

Comment: @Deiv, I disagree.  Once you need it, it is impossible to add it without disruption, because the old event notification must be removed before you can add a new one -- it is not possible to add an overlapping event notification configuration.  While you make that change, you're losing events.  The question is *"What are the advantages?"* and I have answered it correctly -- this stability and flexibility is potentially a very compelling advantage.  Without exception, I configure my notifications this way even if not needed now.

Comment: You can now add multiple event notifications for S3, so there's no downtime if in the future you need to introduce SNS/SQS destinations.